# How do I create another column based on another columns in excel

Tags: excel

I have 3 columns which looks quite like this

| Trsntn 1 | Status 1 | Trsntn 2 | Status 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Payment1 | Deliverd | Payment1 |  |
| Payment2 | Failed | Payment3 |  |
| Payment3 | Settled | Payment2 |  |

So I want to fill the new data in Status 2 with the data from status 1 and sorted as in Trsntn 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple `SORT()` function.

```
=@SORT(A2:C2,1,1,TRUE)
```

For dynamic array approach, try `LAMBDA()` function like-

```
=BYROW(A2:C4,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(SORT(x,1,1,TRUE),1,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi harun thank u for your suggestion, however, the data filled as what u suggested is data copying from column B, what i wanted was data from column B but sorted as in column C - the data in column D should be Deliverd, Settled, Failed

Comment: Yes, put the formula to column D. Then you should get result to column D. Make necessary changes to formula if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need a simple `VLookup()`, like in this example:

[image]

The used function is:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,A$2:B$4,2)
```

This means:

- Look for value C2 (current cell)
- Look into fix array A$2:B$4 (by fixing the array, the references won't change while dragging/dropping)
- Inside the fix array, you need the value of the second column (hence the number 2)

Comment: Thank you so much dominique, this is very helpful as i have 3k lines of row!! Thank you