# Specifying cells with a certain text or value

Tags: excel

How do I get excel to specify the range of cells that has a certain value/text?
I have 5000 texts in a column with various airport names. I have grouped them in alphabetical order and now I would like to find out from which cell to which cell does the airport LAX appears in for example.

Comment: What do you think Excel should "answer" if in your esample the cell A17 is "No" and all others are "Yes"?

Comment: It depends on what you need to do with said information. You could use a conditional formatting to highlight the range, but that won't give directly the desired range's address. You could create a subroutine or a function to return the result as a variable or as a cell's content.

Comment: I have 5000 texts in a column with various airport names. I have grouped them in alphabetical order and now I would like to find out from which cell to which cell does the airport LAX appears in for example

Comment: @sanjaymc'clough: Is your problem solved now?

Answer (score 0):

`VLookup()` to the rescue as you can see from the following screenshot:

[image]

The explanation of the used parameters is exactly the same as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73368075/how-do-i-create-another-column-based-on-another-columns-in-excel/73414286#73414286).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Microsoft365 you can use XLOOKUP() in combination with ROW() for this:

In my example the data is in A1:A72.
I look for the value in column "C"

Please see the last parameter in my XLOOKUP for the first and last...

[image]